# External monitors not detected after BIOS update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, bios

I have a Lenovo Legion Y530 with W10 and ubuntu 18.04. The laptop had some issues with the battery which were solved by updating the BIOS, which I did from windows downloading the update from the official website of Lenovo.

After that, now Ubuntu can not detect the screen (Windows does). I checked the drivers in Software and Updates and it says that it is using the nvidia 390, and `ubuntu-drivers devices` lists that one as recommended. Nvidia X server settings also says that I'm using the nvidia one. But if I go to `settings->details->about`, it shows Intel® HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2).

I did `apt purge nvidia*` and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but all the outputs are the same.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Should we assume you don't have the same problem in Windows?

Comment: No, it doesn't happen in windows, sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that the Secure Boot was activated again, so I just had to go to BIOS menu and deactivate it.

Comment: It's really annoying to deal with all these tiny details :( Thanks for the tip! It worked like a charm.